C Primer Plus Chapter 3 Programming Exercise 6
I am using a Windows 11 laptop.
When I run gcc --version, the computer outputs me the following:
gcc (MinGW-W64 x86_64-ucrt-posix-seh, built by Brecht Sanders, r1) 14.2.0
Copyright (C) 2024 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

When I declare the variable amount_molecules as float or double, the result I end up with is basically correct.
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    float amount_quarts, amount_grams;
    float amount_molecules;

    printf("Please enter an amount of water in quarts:\n");
    scanf("%f", &amount_quarts);
    amount_grams = 950 * amount_quarts;
    amount_molecules = amount_grams / 3.0e-23;
    printf("The number of water molecules in %f quarts is %e molecules.\n", amount_quarts, amount_molecules);

    return 0;
}

However, when I declare the variable amount_molecules as long double, the result I end up with is completely wrong.
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    float amount_quarts, amount_grams;
    long double amount_molecules;

    printf("Please enter an amount of water in quarts:\n");
    scanf("%f", &amount_quarts);
    amount_grams = 950 * amount_quarts;
    amount_molecules = amount_grams / 3.0e-23;
    printf("The number of water molecules in %f quarts is %Lf molecules.\n", amount_quarts, amount_molecules);

    return 0;
}

I compiled and ran it repeatedly on both CLion and Visual Studio Code, and the results were consistent.
That is, when declaring variables with float and double, the calculation results are basically correct.
However, when declaring variables with long double, the calculation results are completely wrong.
I think this should be a precision problem when calculating floating point numbers, but I don't understand why? And I also want to understand how I can avoid making this mistake.

you should make all the variables double. float doesn't have enough precision when you divide by such a small number. The type that you assign to doesn't change how the division is done.

I get 3.166667e+27 for the first version and 3166666666666666388053032960.000000 for the second. They're equivalent to the precision of the float input.

How wrong is "completely wrong"? Off by 1%? Off by 10%? A negative number; infinity; a NaN?

What are your input values and your two (float and long double) output values? Please show some actual inputs and outputs.

Does MinGW do the right thing for %Lf? Compile with -Wall -Wextra - does it warn about expecting a double instead of a long double? gcc.exe (MinGW-W64 x86_64-ucrt-mcf-seh, built by Brecht Sanders) 13.1.0 says `Compiler stderr
: In function 'main':
:22:63: warning: format '%Lf' expects argument of type 'double', but argument 4 has type 'long double' `
I get same results for both codes (changing the Lf to Le). https://onlinegdb.com/puLKB06sU

@001 I assume that's not using MinGW which seems to be a bit broken when it comes to %Lf/%Le.

It's possible that this old answer is still valid

Or, add this as the very first line in your program: #define __USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO 1 and try again

When I enter the value 1.5, the result of both float and double calculations is approximately 4.750000e+25.
However, when I enter the value 1.5, the long double type calculates to 1.173035e-312.
Replacing %Le with %Lf, the calculation result becomes 0.000000 directly.

@TedLyngmo Shouldn't be in case of the UCRT builds I believe.

The root of the problem is probably mixing float, double and long double in the same program, which should never happen. Pick one floating point resolution and stick to it. You should pretty much never be using float anywhere, outside certain mid-range embedded systems.

@TedLyngmo Specifically, I don't think you see the CRT used by the build in --version. I have gcc (MinGW-W64 x86_64-posix-seh, built by Brecht Sanders) 12.1.0 even older but works just fine with -Wall -Wextra etc, no warnings. If you have the MSVCRT then you'll have all those old non-conformance hiccups. If you have the UCRT, they are gone. (The mcf or posix part in --version just refers to the thread model, not the CRT.)

@Lundin Oh, what a jungle.  :-) I only tested it in Compiler Explorer and that's where I got the warning - which also went away with the mentioned #define __USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO 1. Persumably, that made it select the better CRT version. I saw "Select a more ANSI C99 compatible implementation of printf() and friends" in _mingw.h and took it from there :)

Beware casual type conversions
amount_molecules = amount_grams / 3.0e-23; is a float/double division and the double quotient is assigned to a long double.
To fully utilize long double math, use amount_molecules = amount_grams / 3.0e-23L;  (note the L).
Even better, just use 1 floating point type, like long double throughout.
Code may have other issues too
OP comments "the long double type calculates to 1.173035e-312. Replacing %Le with %Lf, the calculation result becomes 0.000000 directly."
This hints that the library is having trouble with "%Lf".
// Instead of 
printf("The number of water molecules in %f quarts is %Lf molecules.\n", 
    amount_quarts, amount_molecules);
// Try
printf("The number of water molecules in %f quarts is %f molecules.\n", 
    amount_quarts, (double) amount_molecules);

to narrow the problem.
